# Is it possible to read data from the serial port using matlab?

Tags: matlab, serial-port

I am reading data from a sensor that is continuously outputting information. I'm new to Matlab so I don't have much experience. I want to modify the code below.
instead of always calling readline() to get the data I want to call it only once and have it always read the next line of data.
``

```
S = serialport('COM5',115200);
data = readline(S);
temp= str2double(split(data,',')); 
data_2 = readline(S);
temp2 = str2double(split(data_2,','));
values= [temp,temp2];
```

``
output :

18.110              24.140
17.200              24.110
0.550               0.740
0.490               0.670

I want it to always read the data since the sensor would always be on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting any error? If so could you please post it to the question?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. I want to alter the code so instead of always calling readline() to extract data I just call it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a while loop, set to terminate either on some condition that you know in advance (an amount of time, or an amount of data) or you can set it to never terminate if you'd rather terminate the loop manually via the keyboard:

```
S = serialport('COM5',115200);
values = [];
while true
    if S.NumBytesAvailable > 0
        data = readline(S);
        values = [values str2double(split(data,','))];
    end
end
```

If you have a sense of how much data you are expecting, you can make this more efficient by preallocating the values array.